# How to post code from mobile?

Tags: support, code-formatting, code, code-block

Can somebody show me how to post code from a mobile device, as I cannot use <kbd>control-K</kbd> or any other combination.

I have tried putting 4 spaces before each line and making 4 new lines in before and after the code.

Comment: If instead your question was: "How can I type Ctrl-K on a mobile phone?" I would have answered: use the [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) but it's probably not worth installing to have a single use; if you frequently need alternative keystrokes it's easy to use.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by:

## Leaving four spaces

If leaving four spaces at the beginning of a line the text should be code:

```
Example
```

## Putting 3 back ticks

You can put 3 backpacks before and after the code:

````
```
Example

```
````

## Using the code button in the tool bar

You can use the code button in the tool bar.

On the iOS and Android app tins will be above the keyboard and on the web it will be above the post box:

[image]

In both cases you need to highlight the text and then press the button.

Answer (score 3):

When I'm on mobile (as I am right now), I post my code by putting 3 backticks before and after the block. Typing this:

````
```
some code here
```
````

results in this:

```
some code here
```